# The entity User is not key value coding-compliant for the key "dateEndSubscription"

Tags: core-data, swift4

I have a swift project with 3 entities in my xcdatamodeld: Access, CustomerInfo and User. I am trying to save the dateEndSubscription separately in the User. When I am trying to save , I get error as : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity User is not key value coding-compliant for the key "dateEndSubscription".' Anyone please help to solve it in swift4.

Comment: Well what does API.DateEnd contain? Also since you are working with a User object, why not do `user.dateEnd = ...` instead of using key value coding?

Comment: Joakim Danielson @It contains date. The response is: "id" : 6884,
  "product" : {
    "dateEndSubscription" : "2016-09-28 21:54:02",
    "delivery" : "2016-07-06 21:54:02",
    "nbrdv" : null,
    "type" : "1",
    "time" : "12 semaines",
    "subscription" : "Renouvellement Détox Express 12Kg",
    "id" : 44
  },
  "cyberaccount" : "11"
}

Answer (score 1):

The json message contains the key `dateEndSubscription` but the attribute in your User entity is named `dateEnd` so they doesn’t match.

A few options to solve this in your `saveUser` method

Change `API.DateEnd` to `dateEnd` but maybe that will infer with the decoding of the json message.

Don't use API key but instead hardcode attribute name

```
 user.setValue(dateEnd, forKey: "dateEnd")
```

and lastly use the property of the User class directly

```
 user.dateEnd = dateEnd
```

You need to change `saveCustomerInformation` as well since you are working with a `User` object there as well although it's unclear why.

Comment: Joakim Danielson@I tried using dateEndSubscription and it gives nothing(neither nil)

Comment: I am telling you to **not** use dateEndSubscription but dateEnd instead.

Comment: Joakim Danielson @ I have changed the attributes in User for dateEnd as dateEndSubscription, so I am using dateEndSubscription. But it doesn't show any value.

Comment: @SwiftGuy have you checked that your json parsing works? Does `let dateEnd = (info[API.DateEnd]?.stringValue ?? "")` assign a value to the variable dateEnd?

Comment: Joakim Danielson@ No, values are not shown here. But I can get the values of userId and other parameters. I have shown you all codes, please help me to solve it. I have deadline for this project.

Comment: But I have solved your issue, now you have another issue with your json parsing.

Comment: Joakim Danielson@ Why it shows blank for the value of dateEnd but shows values for other attributes.

Comment: I don't know, maybe because dateEndSubscription is part of product and not on the top level of the json response? I have no idea how your json decoding works